# Переход в интернет

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Как сделать так что бы при нажатии на кнопку приложение закрывалось и открывался браузер с нужным сайтом?

На свифте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://apple.com")!)
```